# https - Works for the homepage but fails for all other pages

Tags: uri

Running D7 7.43 on Debian 8 with Apache 2.4.10. Everything seems to be set up properly to run https. I go to my dev site https://example.com and all is great. But the moment I go anywhere else (e.g. https://example.com/WhatEverpage_I_go_To I get error 404,

The requested URL /WhatEverpage_I_go_To was not found on this server.

I seem so close but yet not there yet. Where do I look to get this thing working for any page on my site, not just the homepage?

Important note, I changed /etc/apache2/site-enabled/default-ssl.conf

From
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

To
DocumentRoot /var/www/drupal

Before doing that not even the homepage would work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you are using the default .htaccess file. It sounds like your mod_rewrite settings are not working properly and/or not handling the https url.